# How to output an item from an array based on an exact or partial match?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$type = 'oranges';
$kind = 'rang';
$list = array(
    'apples',
    'oranges',
    'pears'
);
foreach ( $list as $name ) {
    if ( strpos( $type, $name ) !== false || strpos( $kind, $name ) !== false  ) {
        $fruit = $name;
    } else {
        $fruit = '';
    }
}
echo $fruit;
```

Based on this example, I would like the output to be `oranges`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after you have `$fruit = 'oranges'`, the loop continues (with `$name = 'pears'`) so then `$fruit` is assigned to `''`.

Just add `break` to stop the loop after the condition is met:

```php
$type = 'oranges';
$kind = 'rang';
$list = array(
    'apples',
    'oranges',
    'pears'
);
foreach ( $list as $name ) {
    if ( strpos( $type, $name ) !== false || strpos( $kind, $name ) !== false  ) {
        $fruit = $name;
        break;
    } else {
        $fruit = '';
    }
}
echo $fruit;
```

Output:

```php
oranges
```